# How to fix web pages are full of squares containing 4 hexadecimal digits each in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, fonts

Frequently when visiting a web page such as YouTube or Wikipedia or other sites there will be squares containing four hexadecimal digits on the page. I assume these are characters which have no symbol in the font being used to display the page. In some cases they are emoji or silly Unicode graphics.

What am I supposed to do to make the web browser display the characters intended by the author of the page? I will try to upload one or more sample screenshots to be clear, but I suspect I'm not the only one who's ever faced this issue.

[image: sample 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a font for rendering Thai characters. Try:

```
sudo apt install fonts-thai-tlwg
```

*Edit:*

To end up with that recommendation I saw via the URL that it was the Thai version of Wikipedia. Then there is the file `/usr/share/language-selector/data/pkg_depends` in Ubuntu which (among other things) specifies default font packages for certain languages. So the command:

```
cat /usr/share/language-selector/data/pkg_depends | grep ^fn:th
```

gave me a suitable font package.

Comment: It's already installed. I'll check again though.

Comment: You were right the package was not installed. After installing it only some of the characters are displayed as intended. Specifically the title bar of the Firefox window is just a string of squares as in the picture.

Comment: I can't upload another screenshot so I hope you can see the title bar in the original because that's still what it looks like.

Comment: @takatakatek: Have you tried to restart Firefox?

Comment: I rebooted the computer and now all the text is displayed as intended (I think). Can you please explain how you knew a font needed to be installed and which one and how to find the package name?

Comment: @takatakatek: Such squares always indicate a font problem. I edited my answer to explain how I found the applicable package.

Comment: That both solves the problem and open many more questions. I thank you sincerely for the assistance.